# Creating a countdown timer that runs even when the application is closed

Tags: android

I am trying to create an application that includes a countdown timer that will run even when the application is not in the main view. I get multiple errors when I try this using a service. Any help regarding how I should go about doing this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Post the code of what you've tried so far.

Comment: Depending on what you  want to achieve it might be enough to save the beginning timestamp and get the current timestamp on startup. Then you can calculate the elapsed time.